# Get loser of match where it only shows winner

Tags: mysql

I have a table called teams (id, name), matches (id, team1, team2), results (match, winner)

How could I select the loser of match x based on the tables matches and results? Is it possible to do with MySQL or do I have to do it on PHP?

EDIT:
matches - team1 and team2 reference teams(id)
results - match references matches(id) and winner references teams(id)

I need to get the id of the losing team.

Comment: what is in the winner column? the team name? could you post some data relevant to the tables?

Comment: Join the `matches` table and the `results` table using `matches_id` and `results_matches_id` (for example), then pull out the other team from the match that doesn't equal the winner from the `results` table

Comment: Edited, I apologize for the lack of clarity, hopefully better now.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you do not allow draws, the loser is the team that participated in the match and is not the winner, so (using X as the match ID):

```
SELECT name
FROM   teams
WHERE  id IN (SELECT team 
              FROM   (SELECT match, team1 AS team
                      FROM   matches
                      WHERE  id = X
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT match, team1 AS team
                      FROM   matches
                      WHERE  id = X) t
              JOIN   results
              ON     t.match = winner.match AND t.team != results.winner)
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the Gordon's answer is better in matter of performance.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with a `join` and `case` statement:

```
select m.id,
       (case when r.winner = m.team1 then team2
             else team1
        end) as loser
from matches m join
     results r
     on m.id = r.match;
```

Because you only want the `id`, the `teams` table is not needed.